# file upload plugin for cakephp 2.x for different model than where implemented

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, cakephp-2.1

I am new to cake and trying to implement image uplaod through my model "ProfileImage".

I have tried several plugins including Meio, Nick's Fileupload , MilesJ, but niether of them worked for my requirement. Checked about the same topics in here too, but no one talks about a separate model or i am doing it wrong or something. [AjaxMultiUpLoad](https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload) uploads images , but doesn't saves related data for the same.

P.S. Most of the plugins i found are for older Cake Versions.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want do accomplish, but MilesJ's plugin works with AJAX and [let you upload through the model](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader#uploading-files-through-the-model).

The reply that Miles gave here may help you [Cakephp Error using Miles J Uploader plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512623/cakephp-error-using-miles-j-uploader-plugin/9528530#9528530)

> P.S. Most of the plugins i found are for older Cake Versions.

Meio-Upload's last release was about 10 months ago, but it works with CakePHP 2.x. The same for MilesJ's plugin, which had its last update just a couple of months ago.

Comment: I want to use different table than image, or otherwise if i can create a association, i want to know know to integrate image upload form from 'Image' model with my profile field forms, which is a diff model named 'Profile'. so that they get saved together. I tried CRUD controller function for the add form, and it gives "find() function on a non object" error for the line : `$profiles = $this->ProfileImage->Profile->find('list');`